# Using -print0 with -o in find

Tags: bash, find

I am using -print0 to modify the output of find to use NULL terminators instead of newlines. However I can't get this to work when using find's -o (OR) function.

This works fine, it prints out a newline-separated list of files that are either not owned by user 'pieter' OR not owned by group 'www-data':

```
find . ! -user pieter -o ! -group www-data
```

But when I append -print0 to this I get no output anymore:

```
find . ! -user pieter -o ! -group www-data -print0
```

This however works fine:

```
find . ! -user pieter -print0
```

What am I missing? I have tried adding various placements of pairs of parentheses but to no avail.

Comment: I'm guessing this would work, but untested: `find . \( ! -user pieter -o ! -group www-data \) -print0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing parens.  Note that you have to escape them so the shell passes them on:

```
find . \( ! -user pieter -o ! -group www-data \) -print0
```

You can find out more about find [on its man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find), especially in the Examples section.

In case you're wondering why that's necessary, it's because of the [order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).  Every expression in find returns either true or false.  If you don't put an explicit operator (`-a`, `-o` or `,`) between the expressions, `-a` is assumed.

So, your original command is equivalent to `find . ! -user pieter -o ! -group www-data -a -print0`, which will only evaluate `print0` on files owned by user `pieter`, but not group `www-data`.

Comment: Great! This works. It makes sense now I look at your solution, grouping the conditions together.