# Maximum limit for 'find / -name 'file' -o -iname 'file2' -o -iname 'file3'..." etc

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find, exec

I am trying to organize a massive amount of files based on file extension.

My code is as follows (sorry for the length):

```
sudo find /malon/tyler/Desktop/test/all/ -iname '*.doc' -o -iname '*.docx' -o -iname '*.log' -o -iname '*.msg' -o -iname '*.odt' -o -iname '*.pages' -o -iname '*.rtf' -o -iname '*.tex' -o -iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.wpd' -o -iname '*.wps' -o -iname '*.csv' -o -iname '*.dat' -o -iname '*.gbr' -o -iname '*.ged' -o -iname '*.ibooks' -o -iname '*.key' -o -iname '*.keychain' -o -iname '*.pps' -o -iname '*.ppt' -o -iname '*.pptx' -o -iname '*.sdf' -o -iname '*.tar' -o -iname '*.tax' -o -iname '*.vcf' -o -iname '*.xml' -o -iname '*.aif' -o -iname '*.iff' -o -iname '*.m3u' -o -iname '*.m4a' -o -iname '*.mid' -o -iname '*.midi' -o -iname '*.mp3' -o -iname '*.mpa' -o -iname '*.ra' -o -iname '*.wav' -o -iname '*.wma' -o -iname '*.3g2' -o -iname '*.3gp' -o -iname '*.asf' -o -iname '*.asx' -o -iname '*.avi' -o -iname '*.flv' -o -iname '*.m4v' -o -iname '*.mov' -o -iname '*.mp4' -o -iname '*.mpg' -o -iname '*.mpeg' -o -iname '*.rm' -o -iname '*.srt' -o -iname '*.swf' -o -iname '*.vob' -o -iname '*.wmv' -o -iname '*.3dm' -o -iname '*.3ds' -o -iname '*.max' -o -iname '*.obj' -o -iname '*.bmp' -o -iname '*.dds' -o -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.psd' -o -iname '*.pspimage' -o -iname '*.tga' -o -iname '*.thm' -o -iname '*.tif' -o -iname '*.tiff' -o -iname '*.yuv' -o -iname '*.ai' -o -iname '*.eps' -o -iname '*.ps' -o -iname '*.svg' -o -iname '*.indd' -o -iname '*.pct' -o -iname '*.pdf' -o -iname '*.xlr' -o -iname '*.xls' -o -iname '*.xlsx' -o -iname '*.accdb' -o -iname '*.db' -o -iname '*.dbf' -o -iname '*.mdb' -o -iname '*.pdb' -o -iname '*.sql' -o -iname '*.apk' -o -iname '*.app' -o -iname '*.bat' -o -iname '*.cgi' -o -iname '*.com' -o -iname '*.exe' -o -iname '*.gadget' -o -iname '*.jar' -o -iname '*.pif' -o -iname '*.vb' -o -iname '*.wsf' -o -iname '*.dem' -o -iname '*.gam' -o -iname '*.nes' -o -iname '*.rom' -o -iname '*.sav' -o -iname '*.dwg' -o -iname '*.dxf' -o -iname '*.gpx' -o -iname '*.kml' -o -iname '*.kmz' -o -iname '*.asp' -o -iname '*.aspx' -o -iname '*.cer' -o -iname '*.cfm' -o -iname '*.csr' -o -iname '*.css' -o -iname '*.htm' -o -iname '*.html' -o -iname '*.js' -o -iname '*.jsp' -o -iname '*.php' -o -iname '*.rss' -o -iname '*.xhtml' -o -iname '*.crx' -o -iname '*.plugin' -o -iname '*.fnt' -o -iname '*.fon' -o -iname '*.otf' -o -iname '*.ttf' -o -iname '*.cab' -o -iname '*.cpl' -o -iname '*.cur' -o -iname '*.deskthemepack' -o -iname '*.dll' -o -iname '*.dmp' -o -iname '*.drv' -o -iname '*.icns' -o -iname '*.ico' -o -iname '*.lnk' -o -iname '*.sys' -o -iname '*.cfg' -o -iname '*.ini' -o -iname '*.prf' -o -iname '*.hqx' -o -iname '*.mim' -o -iname '*.uue' -o -iname '*.7z' -o -iname '*.cbr' -o -iname '*.deb' -o -iname '*.gz' -o -iname '*.pkg' -o -iname '*.rar' -o -iname '*.rpm' -o -iname '*.sitx' -o -iname '*.tarr' -o -iname '*.zip' -o -iname '*.zipx' -o -iname '*.bin' -o -iname '*.cue' -o -iname '*.dmg' -o -iname '*.iso' -o -iname '*.mdf' -o -iname '*.toast' -o -iname '*.vcd' -o -iname '*.c' -o -iname '*.class' -o -iname '*.cpp' -o -iname '*.cs' -o -iname '*.dtd' -o -iname '*.fla' -o -iname '*.h' -o -iname '*.java' -o -iname '*.lua' -o -iname '*.m' -o -iname '*.pl' -o -iname '*.py' -o -iname '*.sh' -o -iname '*.sln' -o -iname '*.vcxproj' -o -iname '*.xcodeproj' -o -iname '*.bak' -o -iname '*.tmp' -o -iname '*.crdownload' -o -iname '*.ics' -o -iname '*.msi' -o -iname '*.part' -o -iname '*.torrent' -o -iname '*.raw' -exec mv {} /home/malon/Desktop/test/ \;
```

If I leave out the -exec portion at the end of the find command, the find command works as expected. This leads me to believe it's something to do with exec, not the find part.

What this code is supposed to do:
Move any detected file up one level from ~/Desktop/test/all/ to ~/Desktop/test/

What this code actually does:
Nothing at all. No error. Looks successful, but the files are never moved.

Are you certain there's no typos?
Pretty certain, seeing as it works with a smaller number of arguments. I also build that command using a loop, lessening the chance of typos.

How did I build this command?
I wrote a bash script here: http://pastebin.com/MeQgH74X

Why have such a huge find command?
Because the actual folder I'm trying to get organized comes from a backup drive that has hundreds of thousands of folders (incremental backups) and iterating through it more than once is painfully long. I'd like to iterate the backup drive once, find the files I need as I go, move them all into a single folder, then iterate that single folder (now holding all the file types I want) and then place the files into folders based on filetype. I hope that makes sense.

Thanks guys!

Comment: As written, it will spawn many many processes.  Could you try:    `--exec mv -t /home/malon/Desktop/test {} +`.  This will move many files with only a single `mv` process, greatly reducing the system load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using -print0 with -o in find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957259/using-print0-with-o-in-find)

Comment: @John1024 This is what I tried, no better: http://pastebin.com/wvYqE8L3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logical and has a higher precedence than logical or in `find`.

```
find ... \( ... -o ..... \) -exec ...
```

Comment: I don't follow. Are you just saying that I should wrap it in parentheses?

Comment: @MALON: Only if you want more than `*.raw` to be processed by `-exec`.

Comment: This is what I have now: http://pastebin.com/ns1vSzjT but it's throwing the following error: find: invalid expression; I was expecting to find a ')' somewhere but did not see one.

Comment: I was able to get it. I put the parenthesis inside the single quote. I'm a dummy. Thank you!