# Iterating over an array of dir names containing spaces has a different behaviour if the array is the result of a `find` command

Tags: arrays, bash

In bash, I think I know how to iterate over an array of strings containing spaces:

```
~ $ arr=( "/home/user/Images/three parts dirname/ccc.png" "/home/user/Images/three parts dirname/bbb.png" "/home/user/Images/three parts dirname/aaa.png" )
~ $ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done

/home/user/Images/three parts dirname/ccc.png
/home/user/Images/three parts dirname/bbb.png
/home/user/Images/three parts dirname/aaa.png
```

I want to do something similar in a script that uses `find`. So I'm doing...

```
~ $ d="/home/user/Images/three parts name"
~ $ arr=( $(find -L "$d" -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.jp*g' -o -iname '*.png' -printf '"%p" ') )
```

...because the command `find -L "$d" -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.jp*g' -o -iname '*.png' -printf '"%p" '`
gives exacltly:

```
"/home/user/Images/three part name/ccc.png" "/home/user/Images/three part name/bbb.png" "/home/user/Images/three part name/aaa.png"
```

The problem is that in this case I have the result below:

```
~ $ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done

"/home/user/Images/three
parts
name/ccc.png"
"/home/user/Images/three
parts
name/bbb.png"
"/home/user/Images/three
parts
name/aaa.png"
```

So I cannot iterate over those files successfully. I know I can avoid spaces in dirs and files names (and I barely have any) but I wanted the script to work anyway, just in case.

What I mean is: why If I use `find` to define the array, the 1st item, i.e., is

`"/home/user/Images/three`

and not

`/home/user/Images/three parts dirname/ccc.png` ?

It seems that with `find` the spaces in the dir names are "hard coded" and/or the double quotes are part of the strings (separated by spaces) themselves.

EDIT here for clarity:
I accepted the answer using `find`. It has to be corrected adding escaped brackets though, according to [stackoverflow.com/a/6957310/1865860](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6957310/1865860). I also wanted to further process the find results, so I had to rely on [stackoverflow.com/a/11789688/1865860](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11789688/1865860).

The final output looks like:

```
readarray -d $'\0' TOT_IMAGES < <(find -L "$i" -maxdepth 1 \( -iname '*.jp*g' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.tif*' \) -print0);
IFS=$'\n';
SORTED_IMAGES=($(sort <<<"${TOT_IMAGES[*]}")); 
TOP4_IMAGES=($(head -n4 <<<"${SORTED_IMAGES[*]}"));
unset IFS
```

Comment: See: why  you [DRLWF](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: The double quotes printed with `find -printf` are literal, not syntactical. See [How can I store the "find" command results as an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23356779/3266847) for a robust way to store the result from `find` in an array.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin : This is nearly correct, but the OP wants to use `-iname`. With your approach you would therefore have to consider the upper/lower case variants, which makes the pattern slightly more complicated. In addition you would have to turn on `nullglob`, for the case that one of your wildcard patterns does not produce any match.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin : Good point!! I forgot about this handy option, since I rarely run this problem. Perhaps you want to write the whole command then as an answer?

Comment: When you do your `arr=(.....)`, word-split occurs and the output of `find` is broken up by the spaces. Is there a particular reason why you want to use `find`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` with `print0` option to have ASCII NUL character separator (instead of NL) and then use `readarray`

```
readarray -d $'\0' arr < <(find -L "$d" -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.jp*g' -o -iname '*.png' -print0)
```

so you don't have to worry about the spaces.

Comment: In which versions of Bash does this work?  [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) does not document `\0` as one of the escape sequences supported in a `$''` string, and embedding null characters in the values of shell variables is generally pretty questionable.  Also, older Bash (version 4.3, say) does not recognize a `-d` option for `readarray`.

Comment: However, if one is willing to assume -- not necessarily safely -- that paths will not contain newlines, then one can use more or less this approach with find's `-print` output instead of `-print0`.

Comment: Answer accepted because it uses `find`. It has to be corrected adding escaped brackets though, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6957310/1865860
I also wanted to further process the `find` results, so I had to rely on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11789688/1865860

The final output looks like: `readarray -d $'\0' TOT_IMAGES < <(find -L "$i" -maxdepth 1 \( -iname '*.jp*g' -o -iname '*.png' -o -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.tif*' \) -print0); IFS=$'\n'; SORTED_IMAGES=($(sort <<<"${TOT_IMAGES[*]}")); TOP4_IMAGES=($(head -n4 <<<"${SORTED_IMAGES[*]}")); unset IFS`

Comment: BTW, `printf '%c' $'\0' | xxd` shows the NUL char, so the sequence works

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with pure `bash`, without using the `find`:

```
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob
arr=("$d"/{*.png,*.jp*g})
```

Comment: To be picky, in accordance with the OP's code, the pattern should be `*.jp*g`, not `*.jpg`. Most likely, he wants also to catch files ending in `.jpeg` and `.jpxxg` and so on.

Comment: This should obtain the wanted final result, but the question asks specifically about using `find`, and their particular attempts to do so.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : Sure, but there is already a `find` solution, and the alternative given by M.NejatAydin is IMO cleaner. I consider both answers useful. The OP can decide, which version he wants to accept.

Comment: Yes, @user1934428, the code presented here is cleaner than using `find` for those cases it handles.  But **that does not make this answer responsive to the question that was actually posed**.

Comment: This is neat (...upvoted), but I accepted the answer with `find`, just because it's what I asked and also it may be expandable if I want to adapt the script to look in nested directories.

Comment: @dentex This is expandable too if you want to recurse directories: Just add the `globstar` option and `arr=("$d"/**/{*.png,*.jpg})` will do it. When you have `bash` (with a recent version), you rarely need the `find`, if all you want is to search based on filenames.